# gnome-terminal and logging

Tags: gnome, bash, gnome-terminal, console

Is there any way to log every that was displayed in gnome-terminal?

for example I have a complex command

```
doSomethingThatPrintoutsAlot ; doSomethingThatPrintoutsAlot2 ; doSomethingThatPrintoutsAlot3
```

I can add `> file`, but than I would have to do it for each command and I have to use tail in another console to see the output. maybe gnome-terminal support logging everything?

there is .bash_history, so .... it might also support this.

Comment: While logging (as asked and answered about) is usually preferable, sometimes might want to run multiple commands on a line and redirect all the output to a file. In `bash` (the shell used by default in the Terminal), you can do that with `( doSomethingThatPrintoutsAlot ; doSomethingThatPrintoutsAlot2 ; doSomethingThatPrintoutsAlot3 ) > file`. Also, any time you use `>` (or `>>`), only output is redirected--the file would not contain characters you entered yourself while the command ran. And they don't include stderr (most error messages): for that too, use `&>` (and `&>>`).

Comment: Also, if you want to run a single command (or a few commands strung together as described above) and have the output go to a file and *also* see it on the screen, then: Instead of `command > file`, use `command | tee file`. Instead of `command >> file`, use `command | tee -a file`. Instead of `command &> file`, use `command 2>&1 | tee file`. Instead of `command &>> file`, use `command 2>&1 | tee -a file`. See also [`tee`'s manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/en/man1/tee.1.html) and the [TDLP Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html).

Comment: @Eliah Kagan thx, that is very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.bash_history` file only stores the command history, not the output. Skimming through `man bash` it does not seem to support that kind of logging.

However there is the `script` command that is able to log the output of any terminal. The usage is quite simple:

```
script ~/mylog
Script started, file is /home/-----/mylog
...
(commands that produce output)
...
exit
Script done, file is /home/------/mylog
```

The output can be read from `~/mylog`.

Comment: +1, I was just writing a similar answer. I would add that a quick and somewhat less flexible alternative could be to set the gnome-terminal scrollback to *Unlimited*.

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering if there are any alternative solutions. I thought about `screen` but that seemed to be a bit overkill...

Answer (score 1):

This does not answer your question directly since you're asking about gnome-terminal, but for completeness sake: `konsole`, the terminal emulator from KDE, makes this as easy as File - Save Output As... - which saves everything in the terminal's scrollback buffer.

It is also possible to set the number of lines stored in the scrollback buffer to unlimited, so this would work even for a very long output.

There's also "Clear Scrollback" option.

You can easily install konsole in Gnome, but that would pull down a few KDE dependencies.

Comment: good to know, thx