# access to all of the written on the terminal

Tags: command-line, bash

I know there is **.bash_history** file on the home directory that stores all of the commands whom user has interred them.

But I am looking for all thing which we see on the terminal. .bash_history file does not contain the result. I need both commands and commands' results. Or at least commands' result. So is there any way? by the way I do not like copy the screen:)

Comment: See also: [How do I save terminal output to a file?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/420981/how-do-i-save-terminal-output-to-a-file)

Comment: Also see http://askubuntu.com/questions/83367/gnome-terminal-and-logging